# Active Record Collection with Subsonic

Tags: c#, subsonic3

I wish to make all my save transactions at the same time.

I'm using Subsonic 3.0 with active record. I've seen some post with MyClassCollection.Save();

However when i "Run Custom tool" i don't get collections. Obviously i'm missing a trick here?

There is of course another way to do this, using BatchQuery. I had an issue with this. Appreciate any thoughts, as you can see i've very new too all this.

```
              var provider = ProviderFactory.GetProvider("MyProvider");
    var batch = new BatchQuery(provider);
    foreach (var cdnEntry in cdnEntries)
    {

        var query1 = new Insert(provider).Into<Clip>
                   ("Author").Values(
                   cdnEntry.Author);

        batch.QueueForTransaction(query1);

    }

    batch.ExecuteTransaction(); // nothing happens as query count alway = 0
```

Comment: It's a typo. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196985/232821

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I obviously need to read on the different patterns available for subsonic. Tho i have got the batchquery working. The above code works. I had few silly sql typo's giving me grief.